# store the return value from a procedure in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a procedure(A) inside another procedure(B) and I want to store the value returned from the procedure A in a variable called `@LogId`.

after executing Procedure A

```
exec TES_usp_getnextlogid
```

it returns something like

```
NewLogId = xxxx
```

I tried doing the following in procedure B.

```
declare @LogId int
exec @LogId = TES_usp_getnextlogid
```

my question is, why doesn't `@LogId` holds the value which is returned from `TES_usp_getnextlogid` Procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use an output parameter instead?

Comment: like in which procedure? sorry. I am kinda new to sql

Comment: There is only one procedure in your example here.

Comment: I suspect that TES_usp_getnextlogid is actually SELECTing the next log id not returning a parameter. You could EXEC into a temporary table (with one varchar column) and then extract the id from the string but it is pretty horrbile.

Comment: I created a temp table. thanks Steve

Answer (score 1):

use output parameter for this, return value should only be used for returning Success/Faliuer status.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE My_Outter_Proc2
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @NextID INT;

  EXEC TES_usp_getnextlogid @NextID OUTPUT

  EXEC My_Inner_Proc @NextID 

END
```